# Autofill New Excel Online Rows based on a cell Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a solution for the following scenerio.
I have an excel sheet that is used to store MS forms responses.
The first cell in every row has a specific value. If a new row is created, the cell should check if the cell is blank is should copy the value from the first cell.
[image]

Something as in this image.

Thanks in advance

The cell (if empty) should be auto filled using the value from another cell in the row.
This should be done automatically when a new row is created.

Comment: You cannot have a formula and a manual input in the same cell. You can do this using a macro to fill blank cells following your rules or you can manually select all blank cells and apply the same formula to all of them. In both cases you need to execute it everytime you open the file. If you really need this to be fully automated try doing it from the MS form that feeds your file.

Comment: You do it in a separate sheet. So, form responses will be stored in a sheet. And in another sheet cells will be updated as per logic defined in formula.

Comment: Thank you for the details ... so how can I handle it in the MS Forms ...